# creating a Pie Chart in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, chart

how can I create the pie chart that displays the Count of columns with filters like (  Active Paths / Courses / Sections /----- this is my column name )from 4 different tables and combined them in one query?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please have a look at [ask]. Currently this question is lacking content and quality, which will possibly lead to it being closed. Please add more details by hitting the [edit] llnk. Good luck.

Comment: I edited the question hope this one is clear. thanks -john

Answer (score 0):

If you add more information on how your schema is structured then we can provide a more specific answer. It's likely you'll want to [JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) your data together into one dataset to consume in your SSRS. Though depending on how your Tables are structured, you may want to [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it too.

If you're using Microsoft SQL Server, you can use a [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15), or even better a [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) (since you'll be filtering and parameters will be helpful here).

Then you need to setup a [new SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-1-creating-a-report-server-project-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15) and configure how the [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-a-filter-to-a-dataset-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) for your stored procedure's [parameters](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/1/8/relating-parameters-filters-in-sql-server-reporting-services.html) are shown in the report.

Finally you can add a Pie Chart via this Microsoft Tutorial: [Add a Pie Chart to Your Report (Report Builder)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-pie-chart-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thanks J.D yes I joined the tables in view and in each table, ( path table, course table, section table, event table )there is an active column ( active path, active course, active section, active event)  so when i do count of each active ( active = 1) it gives me the total of all active( active= 1) from the whole table.

Comment: select count( pathactive) as pa, COUNT (CourseActive) as ca,  COUNT (SectionActive) as sa, COUNT (EventActive) as ea
 from Vw_Wholecurriclum
 WHERE CourseActive = 'Y' and PathActive = 'Y' or  CourseActive = 'Y' or  SectionActive = 'Y' or EventActive = 'Y'  ( this is the query i used and i also used union but in the union the result came in one column but with the above query the result came in diferent column but with the same value)

Comment: @mituhabtay Right, depends on if you're trying to combined multiple similar tables into the same columns (UNION), or if you need different columns from different related tables to make a new result set (JOIN).

Comment: @ J.D ok I will try again using join thanks for clarifying that